# Jquery .css issue on chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, animation, html

i have a script that creates divs with some background image then moves them, it runs great on all other browsers but chrome has is too laggy. I check my codes and i see that when i remove following codes, it works great on chrome too.

```
//imageCount = count of image placed for animation, this loop gets source of
//each image, create divs, then makes each image to background of a div

for(imageNum=0;imageNum<imageCount;imageNum++)
{
var imageSrc= $("#image img:eq("+imageNum+")").attr("src");

 //save image sources for later use
images.push(imageSrc);

 //creating divs
$("#main_cont").append("<div name=img"+imageNum+" class=img_cont></div>");


  //here is my problem
//when i delete .css part works great

$("#main_cont .img_cont:eq("+imageNum+")").width(tWidth).height(tHeight).css({
    backgroundImage: "url("+imageSrc+")",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundSize: tWidth +"px "+ tHeight +"px "

});


  //this part is not about my question, each div's position for animation
var offset = $("#main_cont .img_cont:eq("+imageNum+")").offset();

yPos.push(offset.top);
xPos.push(offset.left);

}
```

a simple version of my codes on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uUj4h/2/ (may take a min to load cause of big images)

if i can't find a solution, i will use images in a div instead of background but for my animation but i need divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the obvious:

```
$("#main_cont .img_cont:eq("+imageNum+")").css({
    width: tWidth,
    height: tHeight,
    background: "url("+imageSrc+") no-repeat top left"
});
```

and just setting background-size in your css.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6TeBk/2/

Or you could try just appending it as an img tag to the start of your element:

```
var imageSrc = new Image();
    imageSrc.src = $("#image img:eq("+imageNum+")").attr("src");
    imageSrc.width = tWidth;
    imageSrc.height = tHeight;

$("#main_cont .img_cont:eq("+imageNum+")").css({ width: tWidth, height: tHeight}).append(imageSrc);
```

Comment: i tried this, even if i set background-size in my style sheet, it still causes lag, if dont set any background-size it works good. But i need to fit image to div so i need to change background-size.

Comment: @Malixxl - There seems to be some raised issues with background-size and especially "cover" on the Chrome Help Forum. Seems those are mostly regarding slow scrolling, but in general it seems Chrome has some problems with this sort of css. I edited my anwer to include a way to append the image as an img tag, that should work in most cases, depending a little on the layout of the rest of that element.

Comment: i've placed images in a div and animating main div's marginTop, i updated my question and added jsfiddle url, try it on chrome and other browsers, only chrome has lag, i think it can be about chrome and big picture display.

Comment: Tested with Firefox and Chrome, and I don't really see the problem. Sure, the animation is a little bit smoother in FF, and because FF caches images differently it loads faster the second time you refresh it, but that's just browser inconsistency that can't really be solved from your end, and I'm afraid you have to live with it or change your code to something else entirely. FIY I created a version with CSS animations, and it's pretty much exactly the same, you can see it [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/uUj4h/4/) -

Answer (score 0):

`background-size` is a CSS3 property, so it might have a greater toll on the browser's speed.

I might suggest using the images within a `<div>` for speed.

Comment: i delete background size and i only left "background: "url("+imageSrc+")""  part in .css function it still laggy, but if i delete this part and set background image from style sheet, there is no lag. So i don't think it's about background-size.

Comment: Can you move the CSS to the stylesheet then?

Comment: i changed my codes to images in a div insted of background, it got still same problem, i updated my question with jsfiddle link, you can see simple version of my codes there. Chrome got lag with that too.